# Bash - How to input lines in rst file after specific line number in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I've got a problem with my i guess simple script.

Situation:
I've got rst files in my repo and i need to find only .rst files (from repo), insert their names into other rst file in specific line (11). This lines that i need to input must be cut - without .rst and in my situation also without ./ before file name.

Example:
*main.rst* contains few lines 
line 1
...
line 3
empty
empty
here should be insert *first_file*
here should be insert *second_file*
empty
line 14

*./first_file.rst* must be insert into *main.rst* in specific line without .rst and ./ part.
I also need to find only .rst files in repo. 
Find part is quite easy i guess just *find . -name '*.rst'*. After that i think that i should use sed but i dont know how to use it correctly and i want to do it in one line with this find line. I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert the output of `find . -name '*.rst'` with `.rst` suffix removed into line 11 of some file, you can:

```
# generate the list with .rst files
# I use `printf "%f\n"` to print only the filename, ie. remove the  `./` part
# sed is used to remove the .rst
find . -name '*.rst' -printf "%f\n" | sed 's/.rst$//' > sometempfile.txt
# Insert the content of sometempfile.txt into 11nth line in the main.rst file
sed -i -e '11r sometempfile.txt' main.rst
# pick up the trash
rm sometempfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! It works as i wanted to. You are awesome :)